# vi: write relative range of lines to a file

Tags: scripting, vi

I need to be able to write a range of lines from a file to another file, I've found the `:<start>,<end>w <new file>` solution but what I need is to be able to search for a string and write a a few lines to another file starting at the "found" location.  Using `.,.` works to get one line but what if I want, say, 10 lines?  Adding to the complexity is that I want to do this in a script.  How do I do that (can I turn on Visual Mode in a script and then move the cursor)?

Comment: Have you thought about using `sed` for this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the nature of the situation dictates vi.

Answer (score 0):

A little more research searching for `vi address range` surfaced the answer:

Although `.,.+10` is supposed to work it didn't but the alternate form `.,.10` did (from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Ranges to give credit where credit is due).